# Gauss map of a minimal surface converse

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, minimal-surfaces

It can be shown that the Gauss map of a minimal surface is conformal quite easily, but does the converse of this statement hold? Specifically, what surfaces have a conformal Gauss map?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: The characteristic polynomial of the Weingarten (derivative of Gauss) map at a point $p$ is, of course, $t^2-2H(p)t+K(p)$. Apply the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem. (You might first observe that the Gauss map is *always* conformal at an umbilic point.)

Even easier, write the Weingarten map in diagonal form. When is it conformal?

Comment: What does the Gauss map being conformal imply about the Weingarten map?

Comment: The Weingarten map is, as I said, the derivative of the Gauss map. What does it mean for a map between surfaces to be conformal?